# Pattern recognition for youtube

Tags: discussion

Would [such question](https://superuser.com/questions/877415/pattern-recognition-for-youtube) could find place here?

> I am looking for software that would allow to match supplied image in
>   video frame. I plan to use it to data-mine Hearthstone videos to get
>   data on what decks are better.
>
> Couple of years ago I saw a guy (I think he's Ukrainian) to
>   demonstrate something similar. He would print screen live feed from
>   his web cam and then would cut part of image and then supply it to the
>   pattern recognition software he was running and it would apply border
>   on matching part on live feed while he was moving camera. It would
>   match it under certain angle. Since Hearthstone cards are always face
>   up it should be possible to reuse this. I tried looking for this video
>   and software without luck. If you know a peace of software that could
>   do something similar(with some tweaks perhaps) or other good idea how
>   to get my hands on Hearthstone game data please let me know.

Comment: Good question, thanks for posting here. I think Sean is on point below.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, the image recognition problem is a valid data science question. However it sounds like you're just looking for a piece of software. That's not on topic here. If you're discussing how to collect images, classify them, how to apply particular software packages and learning techniques, and specific questions about that, it's appropriate.